# Eclipse RCP slf4j logging on file

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, slf4j

I want to develop a custom RCP application using slf4j, logging on a file rather than on standard output.

I've followed this fine tutorial: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseLogging/article.html

This is my activator class:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;

import org.eclipse.core.runtime.FileLocator;
import org.eclipse.core.runtime.Path;
import org.osgi.framework.Bundle;
import org.osgi.framework.BundleActivator;
import org.osgi.framework.BundleContext;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext;
import ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.JoranConfigurator;
import ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.JoranException;

public class Activator implements BundleActivator {


    @Override
    public void start(BundleContext bundleContext) throws Exception {
            configureLogbackInBundle(bundleContext.getBundle());
    }

    @Override
    public void stop(BundleContext bundleContext) throws Exception {
    }

    private void configureLogbackInBundle(Bundle bundle) throws JoranException, IOException {
            LoggerContext context = (LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();
            JoranConfigurator jc = new JoranConfigurator();
            jc.setContext(context);
            context.reset();

            // this assumes that the logback.xml file is in the root of the bundle.
            URL logbackConfigFileUrl = FileLocator.find(bundle, new Path("logback.xml"),null);
            jc.doConfigure(logbackConfigFileUrl.openStream());
    }
```

}

this is my logback.xml file, placed in the root directory of my plugin

```
<appender name="fileAppender" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file>myLogFile.log</file>
    <append>true</append>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<root level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="fileAppender" />
</root>
```

Just using a basic class, like this below, the output always prints on STDOUT, rather than in the file, which isn't created.

```
import org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.MessageDialog;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class AboutHandler {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AboutHandler.class);

    public void execute(Shell shell) {
        LOG.debug("Executing about handler");
        MessageDialog.openInformation(shell, "About", "Eclipse 4 RCP Application");
}
}
```

I've added the dependencies, as suggested in the tutorial, both as *Required* *Plug-ins* and both as *Imported Packages*

Any suggestions? Am I missing something or doing something wrong?

Comment: You don't use `main` for an RCP - you are just running a plain Java program and not using the plugins if you do this.

Comment: I've edit the post! You're right, it was just for try.

Comment: @greg-449 any suggestions?

Comment: I don't use slf4j so I can't really say anything. Is the activator start method actually running? Is it finding the configuration file?

Comment: Yes, because if I change something in the path I have a console message "INFO - No SLF4J Implementation Found"